# Call javascript function (with args) from c#

Tags: c#, javascript, hash

I have a WCF Service and I want to pass a SHA1 hashed string as a result.

On the client side, I have a simple html page with javascript.

I have the code to make the SHA1 string in javascript and I want to use it for both client (dehash the message) and server (hash the message).

The server is in C#.

So, is it possible to call the SHA1 javascript function from C#?

Comment: There is no such thing as "dehashing" a message. The whole point of a hash is that it is inherently one-way.

Comment: `dehash the message`???? A hash function is one way only. The whole purpose of a hash function is to have an unique hash for a given input and that given the hash you can never obtain the input that was used to generate this hash.

Comment: Also, why would you call the JS function on the server? .Net has a perfectly fine implementation of the SHA1 algorithm already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't make sense for two reasons:

1) You can't really share code between C# and JS, these languages are created for completely different purposes and are not interoperable, unless you are willing to allow code generation mess (like in ASP .NET Web Forms). Still, this looks like abuse of [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) that hurts in the long run.

2) SHA1 is one-way algorithm, there is no way to de-hash an encoded string (not talking [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) here). You're using a wrong tool for the job.

Comment: 1) is not necessarily true, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JScript_.NET ...but I agree that this is not a good idea in this context.

Comment: @Jonas, but you can't execute JScript .NET in the browser, so we're still left with interoperability problem, but now between JS and JScript .NET. (Aside from the fact JScript .NET was dead from the beginning, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

you can put a hidden control on your HTML page and put your hashed value in that control and access that control from C#.

Answer (score 0):

NO! But you can put the SHA1 result into an input and post it to server.